# Media Queries - Not working in Edge/IE

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, internet-explorer, media-queries, microsoft-edge

I have a Wordpress website ([www.keentraveling.com](http://keentraveling.com)) and have media queries set up for breakpoints. On Google Chrome they work exactly how I designed. However, on Microsoft Edge when the screen is maximized the content flows all the way to the edges instead of having margins. In Internet Explorer nothing flows to the edge (the header image is supposed to).

Here are my media queries I have set up: https://codeshare.io/26iBj

Any thoughts? Suggestions?

Attached are screenshots of each browser (Chrome is how it should look).

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHZC7.jpg)

[edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLqt9.jpg)

[explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4EI8.jpg)

Comment: Hard to tell just looking at images. Please provide a [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can further assist you.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I've updated the post with a link to my website as well as a link that has all of my media class queriers. Hope this helps.